# Why $p$ has to be a prime in Fermat's theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Fermat's theorem states:

Let $p$ denote a prime. If $p\nmid a$, then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1$(mod $p$).

Euler's generalization of Fermat's theorem states:

If $(a, m) = 1$, then $a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1$(mod $m$).

We know $\phi(m)$ may not be a prime. For example $\phi(5)$ = 4 is not a prime.

Then why $p$ has to be a prime in Fermat's theorem?

Comment: I don't see how your question relates to Euler's generalization. $\varphi(p) = p-1$ for all primes $p$, and this is precisely the exponent in Fermat

Comment: Fermat proved his result for prime moduli, Euler generalized it to composite moduli.  For composite moduli, $\varphi(m)\neq m-1$.

Comment: I do believe it works for $a,p$ relatively primes.

Comment: @lulu I don't mean $φ(m)=m−1$. When m = 4, the numbers coprime to 4 is 1 and 3, so $\phi 4$ will be 2.

Comment: Yes, Euler's Theorem is true.  But I don't see the problem...people generalize theorems all the time, doesn't make the special case uninteresting.

Comment: Now I guess I know what it means. If p is a prime, $a^{p−1}≡1 (mod p)$ is always true. But in some conditions, if p is not a prime, it works also.

Comment: You may be interested in [Carmichael Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).  These are composite numbers, like $561$, that satisfy Fermat's Little Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euler's totient function $\varphi(n)$ is defined to be the number of integers between 1 and n coprime to n. So if $\varphi(n)=n-1$ then all of $1,2,3\dotsb n-2,n-1$ are relatively prime to n. Which means n is prime.